# Access a label's attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, attr

I have some data coming from the server in which I fill A Div in the Html page with. 
The way I write the div is as follows:

```
    <div class="BigDiv"><label class = "AttList" Std_Id="' + Std_Id + '">' + Std_Name +'</label></div>
```

Now, I want the data inside this div. 
There are some other labels inside the div so I use this.children to access this label.

```
        var labels = $(this).children('div');
        var StdName = this.children[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

I want to access the **Std_Id** inside the Std_Id attribute, but I don't know how to do it ... Do you have any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getAttribute`:

```
var labels = $(this).children('div');
var StdId = this.children[0].getAttribute("Std_Id");
```

Note that, according to the HTML5 spec, custom attributes should start with `data-`, though most browsers can tolerate it.

Comment: I'm confused, the OP wanted to use jquery. This solution barley uses jquery at all yet is marked as the answer??

Comment: You don't gain anything in this case.  You don't need to force jQuery into every single line of code you write.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `$(this)` is a reference to the `.BigDiv` element:

```
var StdName = $(this).find('label').attr('Std_Id');
```

Or, similarly, and with the assumption that `this` is the `.BigDiv` element:

```
var children = this.childNodes;
for (var i=0,len=children.length; i<len; i++){
    if (children[i].nodeType == 1 && children[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == 'label'){
        var StdName = this.getAttribute('Std_Id');
    }
}
```

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- JavaScript

  - [`element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute).
  - [`node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType).
  - [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName).
  - [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `attr` method as such,

```
var value = $('.AttList').attr('Std_Id');
```

**EDIT**

OK, so you for *your* implementation, you need to do this...

```
var value = $(this).find('.AttList').attr('Std_Id');
```

Assuming that `this` is the `div` or the parent of that `div`

Comment: I've updated my answer to be a little more of what you need with using jQuery. If you're going to use jQuery, why not use it for something other than a `document.getElementById()` replacement, right?

Answer (score 1):

To save elements, which were selected using a jQuery-Selector, do this:

```
$labels = $('.BigDiv').find('label');
```

Now you can loop through each label with jQuery's foreach loop:

```
$.each($labels, function() {
    var std_id = $(this).attr('Std_Id');
    // do something with std_id
});
```